# How to bring libraries to c++ project on github

Tags: c++, github, redis, visual-studio-2019

I have a c++ console app project created on my computer with Visual Studio 2019. In this project i need to use [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) library. I have installed this library on my computer with [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) and i can use it in my project.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>

class RedisConnectorHelper
{
    static sw::redis::Redis _redis;
    ...
}
```

The problem is when i publish this project to a github repo, anyone who clone my repo cannot run or debug this project because they don't have redis-plus-plus installed on their device.

**So my question is**: is there anyway for them to clone my repo and use right away **without** having to manually install `redis-plus-plus` on their own computer?

Comment: I think adding `redis-plus-plus` as a submodule may be an option. Have you read [Working with submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)?

Comment: You could write a portfile for vcpkg so that your users would need to write only `vcpkg install my-console-app`

Comment: Do you have any more information for us? Have you solve the problem? What was the solution? Mind posting it as an answer to your own question? (that's perfectly fine if you know the answer now - it'll help others)

Comment: i am still looking into you two recommendation and i haven't make much progress. More time is needed is guess. Right now, my team stick with manually install.